# I am doing a mux 4:1 on verilog, but the output is not the expeted

Tags: verilog, multiplexing

I've seen some examples on internet about mux 4:1 on verilog. I've tried to do something but the output is not the expeted. This is the source :

```
module mux41 (a, b, c, d,select,z);

input a,b,c,d;
input [1:0]select;
output reg z;

always@(select )
begin
case (select)
    2'b00: assign z=a;
    2'b01: assign z=b;
    2'b10: assign z=c;
    2'b11: assign z=d;
endcase
end
endmodule
```

and this is the testbench :

```
module mux41_tb;

reg at,bt,ct,dt;
reg [1:0] selectt;
wire zt;

mux41   test(.a(at),.b(bt),.c(ct),.d(dt),.select(selectt),
            .z(zt));
            
initial
begin
     $monitor ("a=%d",at,"b=%b",bt,"c=%b",ct,
                    "d=%b","select=%b",selectt,"z=%z",zt);
                    
    selectt =2'b00;
    #5
    selectt =2'b01;
    #5
    selectt =2'b10;
    #5
    selectt =2'b11;
    #5;
    
end

endmodule
```

but the output is the following :

[image]

My question is what I should chance in both codes (source and testbench).

Comment: Are you using physical switches on your board to select the mux?  If so, you might be subject to glitches caused by bouncing of the switch.  If this is the case, you need to add either an analog or a digital debouncer.

Comment: Hi russell.. Not in all.. I am just trying to simulate a simple mux IC (mux 4:1) in verilog.

Comment: FYI, you should not use `assign` within an `always` block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting

> a=xb=xc=x

Because you never gave a, b, or c any values. You assign `z` to `a` for example, but `a` has no value since `at` has no value, so you're just getting x.

As for

> d = 0111...

It's because of your monitor line

```
$monitor ("a=%d",at,"b=%b",bt,"c=%b",ct,
                "d=%b","select=%b",selectt,"z=%z",zt);
```

You forgot dt

```
$monitor ("a=%d",at,"b=%b",bt,"c=%b",ct,
                "d=%b",dt,"select=%b",selectt,"z=%z",zt);
```

Comment: thank you Downvote. I've improved the testbench and now this is the new output : (Look the update of my post)

Comment: Awesome, now give `at`,`bt`,`ct`,`dt`,and `selectt` values

Comment: Downvote But I suppose I 'm giving values to { selectt } with : selectt = 2'b00; selectt 2'b01, and so on.

Comment: yeahhh downvote. thank you so much man. Wow , At last I get to see what were my problems. Look the update please.

Comment: Sorry for this question. Can I contact to you ?

Comment: If you have another question, post on stackoverflow and comment here again. I'll take a look :)